# Custom Query for fetching data from multiple tables in spring

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Entities:

```java
@Entity(name = "ap_order_paid")
@Component
public class ApOrderPaid {
        
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
        
    private Long order_number;

    @Transient
    private Long invoiceNumber;
    private Long cheqe_number;

    //getter setter
}
    
public class Orders {
    private long order_number;
    private String invoice_number;
}
```

I am running following query in mysql editor and that is working

```sql
select
   v.order_number,
   v.id,
   o.invoice_number as invoiceNumber
from ap_order_paid as v, orders o
where v.cheqe_number like '%1234%' and v.order_number = o.order_number
```

but when I run in spring repository with `@Query` annotation that is **not giving data for invoice_number** only

```java
@Query(value="select v.*, o.invoice_number from ap_order_paid as v, orders o where v.cheqe_number like %?1% and v.order_number = o.order_number", nativeQuery = true)
List<ApOrderPaid> getOrderTaskPaidByCheqNo(String cheqe_number);
```

Comment: probably need `@ManyToOne private Long order_number;`

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned any kind of @column annotation on any column. You are trying to get "invoiceNumber" which is a "transient" field. Use proper annotation so that hibernate able to map DB columns with entity object.

Answer (score 0):

Map the association as a `@ManyToOne` like this:

```
@Entity(name = "ap_order_paid")
public class ApOrderPaid {
        
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
        
    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_number")
    private Orders order;

    private Long cheqe_number;

    //getter setter
}
    
@Entity
public class Orders {
    @Id
    private long order_number;
    private String invoice_number;
}
```

and use a HQL/JPQL query like this:

```
@Query("select v from ap_order_paid as v join fetch v.order where v.cheqe_number like %?1%")
List<ApOrderPaid> getOrderTaskPaidByCheqNo(String cheqe_number);
```